# Install Network Printer Manually (Router : TP-Link TL-WR842ND)

Tags: networking, 13.10, printing, router, ip

Router Model No.:  [TL-WR842ND](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=tl-wr842nd)

After reading [this article](http://www.tp-link.com/en/article/?id=352), I carry on the installation but it does not work. This is the properties page:

[image]

I have attempted to print test page but the status shows me "Processing - Not connected?". The following are the screenshots.

[image]
[image]

If I just directly use the wire to connect the printer, it works.
[usb://FUJI%20XEROX/DocuPrint%20P205%20b?serial=WKK-850460]

I have also tried:

```
http://192.168.0.1/
lpd://192.168.0.1/lp1
socket://192.168.0.1/
http://192.168.0.1/FUJI%20XEROX/DocuPrint%20P205%20b?serial=WKK-850460/
https://192.168.0.1/
ipp14://192.168.0.1:631/lp1
```

No one works.

This is the status of my router.
[image]

Could you teach me how to configure the setting?

---

***Thank you for your attention.***

---

**Update:**

Printer Server : Online
[image]

USB Connected
[image]

Power ON
[image]

It works well on windows only with this official program.
[image]

Comment: I suggest you try: ipp://192.168.0.1:631/lp1

Comment: Printer Status : Processing - The printer is not responding. =[

Comment: Just to make sure: The printer is connected to the router by usb?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: Can you confirm that, in the router, the print server service is set to Online?

Comment: I would also try https, ipps and also ipp14. Try with and without the :631 printing port.

Comment: I have already tried. Not workable.

Comment: Has this been resolved yet? What is the solution?

Comment: Not yet... No one know...

Comment: @CasperLi So did you found a solution to this yet? I'm having the same problem. I can print from windows using the app, but not via ubuntu :(

Comment: The problem has not been resolved. I have contacted TP-link for a solution but they said that they do not support Linux. They do not have the solution.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading the router's firmware to one of the open distributions? (Just a dumb question as nothing seems to work)

Comment: The article says 192.168.1.**10**, and you have 192.168.1.**1**. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Why 192.168.0.1? That's your router.

Comment: I tried to ping `192.168.1.10` or `192.168.0.10` but it is not successful. The printer is connected to the USB port in the router and I guess that the router act as a printer server so I should connect to `192.168.0.1`. However, I do not know the exact protocol and the URI used.

Comment: @A.B. Yes, `192.168.0.1` is my router.

Answer (score 1):

I understand from the screenshot of your router, `192,168.0.1` is your router's address, and you have a separate "printer server" box (TP-PS110U)connected to the router by ethernet on one side and your printer's USB on the other side.

Step 1 says to go directly to step 4... However, step 3 explains the printer spooler web interface at http://192.168.0.10/ -- it may be worth a visit there to check everything is in place.

According to Step 6, the spooler is at 192.168.1.10 by default (to confirm with the information found on the web interface of the print server at http://192.168.0.10), that's where you should find your printer, not at 192.168.0.1, which is your router.

Does it change something?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your link that you referred to as your instrucible, it looks like you skipped step 3.

Step 3 
Open the web browser (like Firefox) and type http://192.168.0.10 in the address bar. Then please go to Setup->TCP/IP page, change the IP to 192.168.1.10 and click Save & Restart button.

If you had done step 3 then your ip address should be 192.168.1.10